# i need help on .append

Tags: python, class, append

openLock is not printing open, it keeps showing close. please whats the problem with my code. thank you

```
class Padlock:
    def __init__(self, combination):
        self.code = combination
        self.code=[]

    def openLock(self,enteredCombination):
        self.enteredCombination= enteredCombination
        if self.code == self.enteredCombination:
            print("open")
        else:
            print("closed")

    def changeCombination(self, newCombination):
        if print == "open":
            print("type in new code")
            self.code.remove([0])
            self.code.append(newCombination)
        else:
            print("open lock first")
lock1=Padlock(1234)
lock1.openLock(1234)
```

Comment: How do you call this piece of code? The only think I see is a class definition. Python will not do anything with a class defintion by itself.

Comment: lock1=Padlock(1234), lock1.openLock(1234), lock1.(4444).   thank you

Comment: [Edit] the question to give a [mcve] that *actually explains the problem*.

Comment: @thecodesalim: but then you only call the `__init__` method which does no printing. Furthermore not that in your `__init__` method, you simply overwrite `self.code` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `self.code` 2 times in the constructor (2. time = []).

I also added a flag `open` to save the state of the lock.
The check `if print == "open"` does not work as you might expect it.

Also there is no need to save `self.enteredCombination= enteredCombination`, as you only need it inside the method.

If `combination` is an `int`, there is no need to use `remove` and `append`.

```
class Padlock:
    def __init__(self, combination):
        self.code = combination
        self.open = True

    def openLock(self, enteredCombination):
        if self.code == enteredCombination:
            self.open = True
            print("open")
        else:
            self.open = False
            print("closed")

    def changeCombination(self, newCombination):
        if self.open:
            print("type in new code")
            self.code = newCombination
        else:
            print("open lock first")

code = "1234"
l = Padlock(code)
l.openLock(code)

newCode = "5678"
l.changeCombination(newCode)
l.openLock(code)
l.changeCombination(newCode)

l.openLock(newCode)
```

Comment: @thecodesalim please accept the answer and close the question for now.